# Catching Error in promise with async/await

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I am trying to catch an Error inside a promise with async/await, but the following code results in "Uncaught Error ... "

```
function messup() {
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        setTimeout(function() {
            throw new Error("Thrown from messup()");
            resolve('hello from messup function');
        }, 1000);
    });
    return promise;
}


async function waitForMe() {
    try {
        await messup();
    }catch(e) {
        console.log ('*****Error successfully caught! *****');
    }
}

waitForMe()
```

Comment: Swearing is **not okay** on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're throwing the error from `setTimeout`, not from a promise callback. As with any other timer callback, nothing will handle that error and it will go straight to the browser's host code, which will probably dump it to the console.

If you want to reject the promise you've returned, use `reject`:

```
function messup() {
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        setTimeout(function() {
            reject(new Error("Thrown from messup()"));
            resolve('hello from messup function'); // This line is pointless now
        }, 1000);
    });
    return promise;
}
```

If you want to have any synchronous errors in the timer callback caught and passed to `reject`, you can use `try`/`catch` for that:

```
function messup() {
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        setTimeout(function() {
            try {
                throw new Error("Thrown from messup()");
                resolve('hello from messup function'); // This line will never be reached
            } catch (e) {
                reject(e);
            }
        }, 1000);
    });
    return promise;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try-catch when used with `await` is specifically looking for the promise to be fulfilled or **rejected**.

If you reject the promise, rather than throwing an error that is unrelated to the promises's resolution (as you currently are), it will be caught via your current setup.

To be clear, the error you are currently throwing is not in any way plugged in to the asynchronous operation you're running.

```
function messup() {
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        setTimeout(function() {
            reject("Thrown from messup()"); //<-- do this instead
        }, 1000);
    });
    return promise;
}
```

Further reading: I cover async/await error handling more in this [guide to async/await](https://mitya.uk/articles/javascript-async-await-part-2#error-handling).